# Mailchimp - send newsletter approve email

Tags: email, mailchimp, newsletter

One of our customers had a campaign and forgot to add "newsletter approve" field on it, he asked us to send an email to the whole list of leads from the campaign to approve newsletter, in case user approved the newsletter from the email he should be added to the newsletter list automatically.

does anyone know how (if) it is possible, i can't find anything about that in mailchimp.

appreciate any help, cheers! :)